# Overriede the specific menu block in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

How can we override the menu block for specific menu?

```
function themename_menu_link(array $variables) {}
```

i am using this function to overide the menu links but it's overriding the all menu's but i want to override only 1 menu which is top menu?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module would greatly assist you as it provides additional theme hook suggestions. With the module, you should be able to add a function `[theme]_menu_link__menu_block__[menu name]()`